# I am confused with calendar class diagram

Tags: calendar, class-diagram

I am trying to draw complete class diagram for calendar super class. I do some draft but really don't know I am on right way or not. In calendar sub class should I include type of calendar or what consist of calendar.Below I made it with type of calendar 
This is my link of calendar class diagram

[image: Calendar diagram]

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Makes (mostly) sense to me.

Have a look, Java does roughly the same:

[image: Type hierarchy]

BUT in your diagram year is a subtype of english calendar. That's not correct.
A calendar may HAVE years but a Year IS NOT a calendar.

Also, a Leap Year should be a subtype of Year (a leap year is still a year).

All class names should be in PascalCase.